# Is it possible to separate rigid part and flexible part from a structure (point cloud)?

Tags: point

Given a structure represented by the point cloud, most part of the points in the structure are rigid, and only a few points are flexible. If I have two representations of the point cloud, and I already known the point correspondence, how can I separate the rigid points with flexible points.

For example, two point clouds represent same slingshot. One of the slingshots has a loose rubber band, and the other one has a tight rubber band. The handle of the slingshot remains rigid. Is there a way to distinguish the deformable part from the rigid part through these two point clouds.

My intuitive solution is to design an Expectation–maximization algorithm.
Expectation: The whole is rigid and calculate the rotation and translation matrix.
Maximization: calculate the points with larger error(distance>k) and exclude this part. Assume that the remaining parts are rigid.

Doing this iteratively until all the point error are smaller than m. (m<<k)

Is this a good idea? Is there any research paper focusing on this question?